# Selecting all text in a UITextField when an user has VoiceOver enabled

Tags: swift, uitextfield, voiceover

In my App I have several text fields which a user can edit. If the text field already contains text and the user begins to edit the text field, I want to highlight all text, so it's easier for the user to delete the content of the field.

Searching the web I have found the solution to set the text fields delegate to self and use the function didBeginEditing(). In this function I just call textField.selectAll(nil). As long as I don't use VoiceOver on the phone this works well. As soon as you turn VoiceOver on the text in a textField doesn't get highlighted when beginning to edit the text field. The function didBeginEditing though is still called. I checked this with a simple print statement.

Has anyone an idea why this isn't working? Is there maybe another way to highlight all text in a text field?

Thank you for every answer!

Answer (score 0):

The selection of text is lost when the VoiceOver selects the element. You should select the text after the VoiceOver focus on element.

On didBeginEditing  you can check if 
`UIAccessibility.isVoiceOverRunning` and then you select the text after one second.

`DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 1) {
  self.textField.selectAll(nil)
}`

Not the best solution, but it's working. Also, for a person with vision problem I don't think is useful to select all the text, eventually you should inform the user that the text is selected.